# C# tool to convert svg to png

Tags: library, c#, svg, image-conversion, png

I am looking for a c# extension or nuget package to convert an SVG to PNG file with high picture quality.

Comment: I have edited out the off-topic coding question. You could place that on [SO], but **not in its current form**: it needs data (pictuires)

Comment: Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524206/480982

Comment: OP is not asking how to write the code using that package/library, but for the package/library itself. So on-topic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the DocumentConverter class from the [Leadtools.Document.Sdk](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads/nuget) Nuget Package. You can use this class to take in your SVG as an input file and convert it to a number of supported Image and document formats, including PNG. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of this package’s vendor).

The C# code to use this would look like the following:

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
   var format = RasterImageFormat.Png;
   var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(inFile, outFile, format);
   jobData.JobName = "SVG to PNG job";
   var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
   documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
}
```